# Changing the app store country

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, ios-appstore

I can't change my app store country on ios 9.   I used to easily do it now it won't let me.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you try?

Answer (score 1):

What the error message you having ? 
did you try on a different devices such a computer?

Have you checked this : 
Change your iTunes Store country or region - Apple Support
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389

Did you have an Apple Music subscription or iTunes Match subscription ? or may be some store credit? or unpaid order?